# Python Implementing protobuf --decode-raw in python

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, protobuf-python

I am dealing with the protobuf protocol and I encounter the need of decoding messages of unknown fields and types. I know `protoc --decode_raw` does a good job at that (alas not precise but good enough).

I was thinking about running `protoc --decode-raw` in a shell and let Python read its content, parsing it as a dictionary, but I figure it is the last resort of implementation.

Is there a Pythonic method of implementing the same functionality?

Answer (score 5):

Use blackboxprotobuf

`pip install bbpb`

It can parse protobuf buffers without proto file definitions

`message, typedef = blackboxprotobuf.protobuf_to_json(data)`

Comment: Yeah man this was silky smooth!

Answer (score 2):

From https://pypi.org/project/bbpb/

`pip install bbpb`

Demo code:

```py
import blackboxprotobuf
import base64
import json
data = base64.b64decode('KglNb2RpZnkgTWU=')
message,typedef = blackboxprotobuf.protobuf_to_json(data)
print(message)
    # {
    #   "5": "Modify Me"
    # }
    
type(data) 
# bytes
```

Parse from a website content with `content-type: application/x-protobuf` and `content-encoding: br`

```py
import requests
response = requests.get('http://www.example.com/some_protobuf_type_content')

with open('somefile.bin', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content)
file = 'somefile.bin'
with open(file, 'rb') as fr:
    data = fr.read()

# or just use `data = response.content`  
message, typedef = blackboxprotobuf.protobuf_to_json(data)   
type(message) # str
msg_data = json.loads(message)
type(msg_data) # dict
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same need, but there is no official API for it as far as I've found. There are some internal methods, such as accessing `msg._unknown_fields` on an empty message and [internal.decoder](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/python/google/protobuf/internal/decoder.py). But those are not part of the official API and vary between versions.

If the shell approach is too hacky, your best bet is implementing the decoding based on [documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding) with custom Python code.